# jQuery redirect mobile under certain circumstances

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, mobile

I am trying to get a jQuery script to redirect to a mobile optimized version of my site under certain circumstances. Basically, if the browser is mobile, it will redirect to the mobile, unless in the URL it gets the argument "mobile=0". I've got a way to detect if it's mobile, and I have a plugin which lets you get arguments from the URL with jQuery (http://www.mathias-bank.de/2007/04/21/jquery-plugin-geturlparam-version-2/) which works.

The flow I'd like to have is if it's desktop, set a mobile variable to 0, and not redirect. Then, if it's mobile, redirect unless the mobile variable is set to 0 by the url.

Right now, it isn't redirecting if I am on a mobile browser. I have tested that my redirect works on mobile, but after adding the url parameters, it stopped working.

I started coding, but as I am a bit new at javascript, I know I am making some mistakes. My code so far is:

```
 var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|iemobile|ppc|smartphone|blackberry|webos|)/);
    var mobile = $.getURLParam("mobile");
    if (!agentID) {
        mobile = "0";
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    if ($.getURLParam("mobile")==0) {
          return false;
    }
else {
    if (agentID) {
        window.location.replace("http://remiwebo.vacau.com");
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, what is the problem with the code you've got so far?

Comment: Right now, it isn't redirecting if I am on a mobile browser. I have tested that my redirect works on mobile, but after adding the url parameters, it stopped working. EDIT: realized I forgot to add that. thanks!

Comment: If it stopped working after you added the $.getURLParam("mobile") have you tested to see if you are getting a value from that jquery method? (An alert message would suffice). But looking at your logic,  if it's not a mobile device, you're never going to be able to parse the mobile parameter

Comment: I'm getting the $.getURLParam("mobile") from the jQuery plugin that I linked to in the question. (and it does work, I tested it making sure I got variables from it) Do you have any suggestions on how I could properly parse it? I'm looking to get the mobile parameter always at 1, unless the URL says 0, or I am on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're logic might be a bit more complex than it needs to be.

> The flow I'd like to have is if it's desktop, set a mobile variable to
>   0, and not redirect. Then, if it's mobile, redirect unless the mobile
>   variable is set to 0 by the url.

1) if it's a mobile - Redirect.

2) if it has mobile=0 do NOT redirect.

3) if it's a PC do NOT redirect.

What about testing a mobile version on your computer? (mobile = 1)?

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
document.write("Device Agent: " + deviceAgent);
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|iemobile|ppc|smartphone|blackberry|webos|)/);

document.write("</br>Agent ID: " + agentID);


//This doens't work well on JSfiddle, but it wwill work (non jquery way)
var mobile = getUrlVars()["mobile"];
document.write("<br />Mobile : " + mobile);

  //If we're a cell phone AND if there is no sign of the mobile parameter, or it is other than 0, redirect.
  if (agentID.length > 3 && (!mobile || mobile != "0")) {
      document.write("<br />GO GO GO TO MOBILE SITE");
      window.location = "mobile.verison.of.my.site.com"
  }
  else {
      document.write("<br />DO NOT GO TO MOBILE");
      return false;
  }
      // Handler for .ready() called.


function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

update: agentID will = ", ", a 2 character string if it doesn't find anything in the deviceAgent string. So rather than testing if it's null, you can check the length of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/3zv64/

Comment: Only problem with that code is that it's redirecting on both PC and mobile. It would need to be that on PC, mobile is set to 0 automatically.

Comment: Thank you! One issue with your code is that on (for example) my ipod touch, I got "ipod,ipod". So, I reversed agentID.length > 3 to agentID.length < 3, and it works perfectly! Thanks again for your help. :-)